# Transforming JSON-like data into a string, node mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

Quick edit - I am a complete beginner in web development, so I realize the solution might be stupidly obvious.

I'm attempting to insert a data set into a MySQL db through nodejs/expressjs/mysql.

I have a successful connection to the db and can query from it without issues.

Here is my post code:

```
app.post('/pyme', function(req,res){
    console.log("Data being POSTED to db...");
    var post = req.body;
    console.log(post);
    var sql_insert_pyme = 'INSERT INTO pyme(NombreComercio,NumeroTelefono) VALUES =?';
    sql.query(sql_insert_pyme,post,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    });
});
```

The POST data I am getting looks as follows:

```
{ NombreComercio: 'Sebastian Avila',
  NumeroTelefono: '71021714' }
```

I need a method to break that post into a simple:

```
"'Sebastian Avila', '71021714'"
```

Basically I want to end with:

```
post = "'Sebastian Avila', '71021714'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce a JSON object to an array (you can reduce it to string straight away, but array gives you more control over) and join it.

```js
var postObject = {
    NombreComercio: 'Sebastian Avila',
    NumeroTelefono: '71021714'
}

var postArray = Object.keys(postObject).reduce(function(reduced, jsonKey) {
    reduced.push("'" + postObject[jsonKey] + "'");
    return reduced;
}, []);

var postString = postArray.join(',');

console.log(postString);
```

If you want query parameters to be dynamic, you can as well set `Object.keys(postObject).join(',')` in columns names part of the query.

Comment: This solved it. Thanks! I was running around in circles figuring out how to reduce and push the object

Comment: You're welcome. Simple stuff and now you know how to handle it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 var postObject = {
NombreComercio: 'Sebastian Avila',
NumeroTelefono: '71021714'
}

var vals = Object.keys(postObject).map(function(key) {
return "'"+postObject[key]+"'";
});

console.log(vals.join(','))
```